# Python: Convert Months into Quarters conditional on second variable

Tags: python, date, char

I asked the same question for `R` and I obtained the answer, I hope to obtain it for `Python` too.

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
 tenor   delivery_window
 <chr>   <chr>          
 1 month   Nov 22         
 2 quarter Jan 22         
 3 year    Cal 24         
 4 year    Cal 22         
 5 month   Feb 22         
 6 quarter Jan 21         
 7 month   Sep 22         
 8 quarter Jan 21         
 9 month   Jun 21         
10 month   Aug 21
```

And which I want to turn into something like this:

```
 tenor   delivery_window new_tenor
 <chr>   <chr>           <chr>    
 1 month   Nov 22          Nov 22   
 2 quarter Jan 22          Q1 22    
 3 year    Cal 24          Cal 24   
 4 year    Cal 22          Cal 22   
 5 month   Feb 22          Feb 22   
 6 quarter Jan 21          Q1 21    
 7 month   Sep 22          Sep 22   
 8 quarter Jan 21          Q1 21    
 9 month   Jun 21          Jun 21   
10 month   Aug 21          Aug 21
```

That is, if the `tenor` is `quarter`, I want to show only the quarter corresponding to the `delivery window`, not the month. Monthly and Yearly tenors can remain as they are.

The `new_tenor` should be `Q1 YY` for months from `Jan YY` to `Mar YY`, `Q2 YY` for months from `Apr YY` to `Jun YY`, `Q3 YY` for months from `Jul YY` to `Sep YY`, and `Q4 YY` for months from `Oct YY` to `Dec YY`.

Can someone please help me again? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
def ConvtoQuarter(tenor, delivery):
  if tenor == "quarter":
    if delivery[:3] in ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']:
      return "Q1 "+delivery[-2:]
    elif delivery[:3] in ['Apr', 'May', 'Jun']:
      return "Q2 "+delivery[-2:]
    elif delivery[:3] in ['Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep']:
      return "Q3 " + delivery[-2:]
    elif delivery[:3] in ['Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']:
      return "Q4 " + delivery[-2:]
  else:
      return delivery
df = pd.DataFrame({"tenor":['month', 'quarter', 'year', 'year', 'month', 'quarter'],
                   "delivery":['Nov 22', 'Jan 22', 'Cal 22', 'Cal 22', 'Feb 22', 'Jan 21']})
df['NewTenor'] = df.apply(lambda x: ConvtoQuarter(x['tenor'], x['delivery']), axis=1)
df
```

Output:

```
tenor   delivery    NewTenor
0   month   Nov 22  Nov 22
1   quarter Jan 22  Q1 22
2   year    Cal 22  Cal 22
3   year    Cal 22  Cal 22
4   month   Feb 22  Feb 22
5   quarter Jan 21  Q1 21
```

Comment: Thank you very much and welcome, your answer gives the expected result.